# Wcf visual studio tutorial

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I am completely new to WCF ... I would like to read a tutorial on how to create a simple wcf service and create a console application to use the service. I saw some tutorials online, but they arent properly written ...It would be great if someone can help me . Thanks

Edit: I tried to implement a wcf example, but i get the following error "There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/Reverse" ... The full code is here

http://pastebin.com/NUazyyD8

Please take a look

Comment: I read a tutorial from here http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication ... But,i get an error stating that "There is no endpoint listening at localhost:8080/wcfservice" ...

Comment: it sounds like you just don't have your service setup correctly. Are you sure your service is called `wcfservice`? And that it's running on port 8080?

Comment: @Justin Satyr: how do i check if the service is setup correctly ?

Comment: Here is the full code of my application http://pastebin.com/NUazyyD8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)".

Comment: Hi .. thanks for the link . When i press ctrl+F5 to run , it starts the browser and shows a directory structure. It doesnt launch a command prompt as per ur article. How to run it in this case? Thanks

Comment: Right-click the .svc file and use "View in Browser". Better yet, you should create a client program to consume the service - preferably a Unit Test, so that your tests will be a reproducible part of your Visual Studio solution.